# Android app side (Server) python (client) in Socket Programming

Tags: java, python, android, sockets

I am aiming to set up a server in android studio.I want my android application to receive external data using socket programming, so I wrote the codes I have shown below. I am having trouble learning the server IP of my Android application. That's why the connection is refused.

This server code in android studio:

```
package com.tefrikatli.fatura.myapplicationas;

import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class MyserverOdom implements Runnable{

    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket mysocket;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String message;
    EditText dt;


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            dt.findViewById(R.id.textView22);
            ss = new ServerSocket(6000);

            //ss.accept();
            while (true) {
                mysocket = ss.accept();
                dis = new DataInputStream(mysocket.getInputStream());
                message = dis.readUTF();
                dt.setText(message.toString());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

this is anaother  file :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    ImageButton manuelgec;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        manuelgec =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.manuelTemizlik);

        manuelgec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gec = new Intent(MainActivity.this,manuel_temizlik.class);
                startActivity(gec);
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyserverOdom());
                myThread.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

```
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.220  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::878d:6c3d:4ca4:4456  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:8c:a0:32:32:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 647309  bytes 75238346 (75.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1086  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 681546  bytes 102623647 (102.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

mynet ip is: 192.168.43.220

I write ifconfig :

The client socket is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from math import degrees
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from nav_msgs.msg import OccupancyGrid
import cv2
import socket

global s 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.43.220', 6000)) #IP is the server IP

def odom_cb(msg):
    seconds = rospy.get_time()
    if (int(seconds) % 2 == 0):
        try:
            image = cv2.imread("/home/abdulsamet/catkin_ws/src/mobil/src/tubitak_v1.yaml.pgm")
            den = image.shape

            try:
                xeksen = str(int(den[0]*11/20+(msg.pose.pose.position.x*19.2)))
                yeksen = str((int(den[1]*11/20-msg.pose.pose.position.y*19.2)))
                tam = xeksen + "," +yeksen
                s.send(tam.encode())

            except socket.error as msg:
                print("de: ",msg)

        except socket.error as msg:
            print("Hata:",msg)



rospy.init_node('odom_to_path')
odom_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, odom_cb, queue_size=10)

rospy.spin()
```

This error is shown

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/abdulsamet/catkin_ws/src/mobil/src/deneme.py", line 12, in 
> s.connect(('192.168.43.220', 6000)) #IP is the server IP
> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

How to connect android app with my python script can someone help me what topics should i look at about this issue.

Comment: `The client server is :` ?? Now what is it? A client or a server? Not both please.

Comment: `I am having trouble learning the server IP of my Android application` Well then tell why you use the one you used now.

Comment: `mynet ip is: 192.168.43.220` ? Of the server or of the client?